# Does SSRS in an Azure Virtual VM support Report Server Databases as Azure SQL Database and/or Azure SQL MAnaged Instance?

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-sql-managed-instance, reporting-services-2016, azure-sql-reporting

I installed SSRS into an Azure VM (IaaS). In the ssrs configuration manager, I tried the report server databases point to an Azure SQL Managed Instance database, but the connection didn't work. I would like to know if SSRS in an Azure VM support Report Server Databases as Azure SQL Database and/or Azure SQL MAnaged Instance. If it is supported, can you please share any documentation about that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge Report Server databases cannot be hosted on Azure SQL Database as I mentioned on [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/81c9197c-9af8-4002-9a80-cd4adc1f9841/report-server-database-migration?forum=ssdsgetstarted) MSDN forum thread.

As long as I know, the Report Server database can be hosted on a Managed Instance and is mentioned by a Microsoft Data Platform MVP on [this](https://prologika.com/azure-sql-database-managed-instance-the-good-the-bad-the-ugly/) article. You won't find any official documentation on how to do this. This scenario makes little sense to me, because you will be paying money for a SQL VM and a Managed Instance. You will be paying SQL licenses for both. You save money if you have SSRS and its databases on the VM,